# How to use a router.get request in a router.post request of a differents routes nodejs

Tags: node.js, post, import, get, requirejs

I work on a Nodejs application and I would like to have the result of a GET request in a POST request, when the two request are not in the same route.

I explain you in details :

I have in my `libellecsv.js route` this following code :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Libellecsv = require('../../models/Libellecsv');

//@route   GET api/libellecsv
//@desc    Return all the libelle of the csv present in the database
//@access  Public
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  Libellecsv.find(function (err, libelle) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    res.json(libelle);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And i want to use the result of this get request in my post request in my `students.js routes` :

```
//@route   POST api/students
//@desc    Fill the database with the json information
//@access  Public
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {

// HERE I WANT TO PUT THE RESULT OF THE LIBELLECSV GET REQUEST IN A VARIABLE

}
```

How can i do that ? It's certainly a basic problem, but I can't find a solution.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly just reuse the `Libellecsv` repository in your `post`-handler, although I'd wrap it in a promise in order not to have too many callback chains (also this needs some proper error handling of course):

```
//@route   POST api/students
//@desc    Fill the database with the json information
//@access  Public
router.post('/', async(req, res) => {
    const libelle = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Libellecsv.find(function (err, libelle) {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                resolve(libelle);
            });
        });
    // do something with libelle here
    console.log(libelle)

}
```